# Load external libraries and SDK with appcelerator hyperloop

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I'm working on a iOS and Android DVR app with remote controls.
I need to use a third-party library for network communication and video encoding, via hyperloop programming.

At the moment I tried importing the iOS version libraries.
The library consists of a static file libDVR_NET_SDK.a and a "include" folder with several .h header files inside.

I followed the official documentation by creating the references in the appc.js file:

[appcelerator.com iOS Hyperloop Programming Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide-section-src-46253491_safe-id-aU9TSHlwZXJsb29wUHJvZ3JhbW1pbmdHdWlkZS1DdXN0b21GcmFtZXdvcmtzJkxpYnJhcmllcw)

```
module.exports = {
    hyperloop: {
        ios: {
            thirdparty: {
                'libDVR_NET_SDK': {
                    source: 'platform/ios/SDK/include',
                    header: "platform/ios/SDK/include",
                    resource: 'platform/ios/SDK'
                },
                'MediaPlayerLib': {
                    source: 'platform/ios/MediaPlayerLib/include',
                    header: "platform/ios/MediaPlayerLib/include",
                    resource: 'platform/ios/MediaPlayerLib'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I can not understand how to call the external library from javascript code, at the moment I tried:

```
var libDVR_NET_SDK = require("libDVR_NET_SDK");
```

But the following error is generated:

```
Script Error Couldn't find module: /hyperloop/libdvr_net_sdk/libdvr_net_sdk for architecture: x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperloop docs says : **This has been deprecated in Hyperloop 2.2.0 and will be removed in Hyperloop 3.0.0. Place it into your iOS platform directory instead and it will be automatically detected.**

So, try putting your library in **Project -> app -> platform -> ios** folder & it will automatically detect it.

To use in js code, you can try to call it as mentioned in that library docs considering the names to be same as if you were calling them in native iOS.

I found similar to Android here : **[Hyperloop Android 3rd Party Example](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/tree/master/app/platform/android)**. It contains libraries in similar folder & you can check how it's used further in titanium app code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to see the example.
However, it seems to me that the latest release of hyperloop is 2.1.3. I guess 2.2.0 can be released with the next version of SDK. Know if I can install a pre-release to test the functionality?

Comment: Version 2.2.x has recently been released, but both using the appc.js file and without I can not understand if the library is statically imported or how to retrieve it.
The Appcelerator Guide is not very clear about the rules on how can external libraries be called when imported with require() ... From the filename? From the name of the class inside? From a self-generated name by hyperloop, if you no longer use the appc.js file?